Spring Boot: Fetching Data from Multiple Endpoints in Spring Boot Application
In controller i have productController endpoint:
  @GetMapping(path = "/details/{productName}")
        public @ResponseBody Product getSingleProductDetails(@PathVariable String productName) {
            Product product = productService.getSingleProduct(productName);
            productService.getIngredientsList(product);
            return productService.getSingleProduct(productName);
        }

and i get in postman:
{
    "id": 102,
    "name": "AspirinC",
    "ingredient1": "Acidum acetylsalicylicum 400mg",
    "ingredient2": "Acidum ascorbicum 240mg",
    "ingredient3": null,
    "ingredient4": null,
    "ingredient5": null
}

and then i extract only the ingredients:
public List<String> getIngredientsList(Product product) {
        List<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> formattedIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
        ingredients.add(product.getIngredient1());
        ingredients.add(product.getIngredient2());
        ingredients.add(product.getIngredient3());
        ingredients.add(product.getIngredient4());
        ingredients.add(product.getIngredient5());
        ingredients.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
        System.out.println("Ingredients:");
        for (String ingredient : ingredients) {
            formattedIngredients.add(formatIngredient(ingredient));
        }
        System.out.println(formattedIngredients);
        return formattedIngredients;
    }



    private static String formatIngredient(String ingredient) {
        String[] parts = ingredient.split("\\s+");
        if (parts.length > 1) {
            StringBuilder formattedIngredient = new StringBuilder(parts[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
                formattedIngredient.append(" ").append(parts[i]);
            }
            return formattedIngredient.toString();
        }
        return ingredient;
    }

and the console out is
[Acidum acetylsalicylicum, Acidum ascorbicum]

and in the drugController i have:
  @GetMapping(path = "/{activeIngredient}")
    public @ResponseBody Drug getDrugByActiveIngredient(@PathVariable String activeIngredient) {
        return drugService.getDrugByActiveIngredient(activeIngredient);
    }

and in postman
{
    "id": 554,
    "name": "Acidum acetylsalicylicum",
    "time": "As needed",
    "maxDosage": 4000,
    "dosage": "500mg tablets, take 1-2 tablets every 4-6 hours as needed for pain or fever",
    "meal": "Can be taken with or without food",
    "effect": "Pain relief, Fever reduction",
    "mechanism": "Works by inhibiting the production of prostaglandins in the brain",
    "indication": "Mild to moderate pain, Fever",
    "contraindication": "Hypersensitivity to paracetamol, Severe liver impairment",
    "form": "Tablet",
    "synonym": "Acetaminophen, Tylenol"
}

And what i want to achive is that:
I send the request to http://localhost:8080/product/details/{name}, then i get the igredients, get the list of them and each of them i send to http://localhost:8080/drug/{name} and collect the information about the substances. How to do it in Spring?
EDIT:
i wrote:
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        for(String ing: formattedIngredients){
            String drugUrl = "http://localhost:8080/drug/" + ing;
            try {
                Drug drugInfo = restTemplate.getForObject(drugUrl, Drug.class);
                System.out.println("Information for " + ing + ":");
                System.out.println(drugInfo);
            } catch (RestClientResponseException e) {
                System.out.println("Error retrieving information for " + ing + ": " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return formattedIngredients;

and i got:
Information for Acidum acetylsalicylicum:
phcare_project.entity.Drug@de1d06d
Information for Acidum ascorbicum:
phcare_project.entity.Drug@ddca2f4


This is not a solution that follows SOLID principles, but without seeing more of your code this is the best I can suggest. You can modify your getIngredientsList method like this:
public List<String> getIngredientsList(Product product) {
        List<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> formattedIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
        ingredients.add(product.getIngredient1());
        ingredients.add(product.getIngredient2());
        ingredients.add(product.getIngredient3());
        ingredients.add(product.getIngredient4());
        ingredients.add(product.getIngredient5());
        ingredients.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
        System.out.println("Ingredients:");
        for (String ingredient : ingredients) {
            formattedIngredients.add(formatIngredient(ingredient));
//this is the modification:
 System.out.println(drugService.getDrugByActiveIngredient(ingredient);
// end of modification.

        }
        System.out.println(formattedIngredients);
        return formattedIngredients;
    }

In order for this method to work, please do not forget to add annotation @RequiredArgsConstructor to your ProductService class, and import DrugService:
private final DrugService drugService;

